# GRUB installation Windows and Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd, mbr

I have two hard drives, one with no partitions and Windows 7 installed on it(ssd):
/dev/sda
And the second is for Ubuntu 13.04 (hdd), and is partitioned for:
/dev/sdb1   /
/dev/sdb2   /home
/dev/sdb3   swap

What I need to know is where the GRUB should be installed, to the Windows disk or somewhere on the Ubuntu disk?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install grub to `/dev/sdb` and make that the default disk to boot from in BIOS. Grub will usually pick up your Windows installations and offer to boot that instead of Linux during system boot.

This has the advantage, that grub does not touch Microsoft's boot loader and you can always revert the boot disk entry in BIOS.

Comment: Just /dev/sdb/ or /dev/sdb1 or 2?

Comment: Clarified my answer.

Comment: So 'Device for boot load install' would be /dev/sdb/ and in BIOS I can change boot disk too that disk? GRUB will handle the rest?

Comment: Yes. Leave the final `/` though.