# Forced to boot into Windows 7 in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, mbr

This follows on from my earlier question [GRUB installation Windows and Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350381/grub-installation-windows-and-ubuntu-13-04). I'm trying to get a Ubuntu and Windows dual boot working.

I have installed GRUB as I was advised to but now no matter which HDD I chose to boot from it always loads up Windows, and GRUB doesn't even seem to appear. Boot without the Windows 7 HDD in gives the message

> Reboot and select proper boot device

Out of my depth here, any advice would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to reinstall the grub bootloader. You can achieve this via the installation cd by doing the following in a terminal:

- Mount the Ubuntu system partition: `sudo mkdir /mnt/ubuntu` and `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/ubuntu`
- Mount `/sys` `/proc` and `/dev`: `sudo mount -t proc none /mnt/ubuntu/proc` and `sudo mount --rbind /sys /mnt/ubuntu/sys` as well as `sudo mount --rbind /dev /mnt/ubuntu/dev`
- chroot into the installed ubuntu system: `sudo chroot /mnt/ubuntu /bin/bash`
- Now in the chroot you can update the Grub config: `update-grub`
- And install Grub to whatever hard disk you like: `grub-install /dev/sda` or `grub-install /dev/sdb`

Then reboot your system and choose the right hard drive to boot your system!

Comment: Maybe there is an easier way via some rescue option of the ubuntu install cd, but I don't know for sure as I'm not using Ubuntu anymore.